# cURL from host-to-container works, but from container-to-container does not

Tags: curl, docker, digital-ocean

Title pretty much says it all, but let me give some context.

I have a MySQL instance running one one container, an API running in another, and a script running in a third. The script hits (or is supposed to hit) the API running in the second. These are all on the same physical machine (on DigitalOcean).

I have the port we're using (8080) exposed in the Dockerfile for the API, and exposed using `-p 8080:8080` at runtime for the API. I have the script pointing to the API IP correctly.

In other environments (AWS, RaspPI), this setup works fine. But, on DigitalOcean, it's not working at all. My script's attempts to hit the database API simply fails.

Strangely enough, cURLing from the host machine to an API endpoint works fine, so the API itself is working. cURLing from inside the script docker container using docker exec, however, leads to a timeout every time - the same problem I'm having from within the script.

My only two guesses are that this has something to do with DigitalOcean configuration settings for their Docker droplet, or that Docker has inter-container communication configuration that I'm missing.

TL;DR: cURL from host machine -> Docker container API works. cURL from Docker container on same machine -> Docker container API does not.

Regardless, if any of you guys want more information, don't hesitate to ask :) Cheers!

Comment: when you say `script's attempts to hit the database API simply fails`, can you enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE and show us what curl says?

Comment: Sorry, was a very poor description here. The script uses the npm request module (node) - when I say it fails, I mean it times out. I'll try using verbose cURL and post here in a moment.

Comment: What ip or hostname do you use when trying to reach another container ?

Comment: ```sudo docker exec jolly_montalcini curl -verbose http://db.xxxxx.co:8080/races/status/0
* Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx...
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:01:30 --:--:--     0```

Comment: The above is probably largely useless, but that's the verbose cURL - and basically it shows the same, a complete timeout. @rckrd

Comment: @rckrd - I'm using the host droplet's hostname to connect via the other container. This has worked on all other environments.

Comment: "I'm using the host droplet's hostname to connect via the other container" -- that's not how it's done. You need to use the bridge network IP of a target container, use `--link` to assign a pseudo-hostname to it, or better yet, use Docker Swarm for service discovery.

Comment: Perhaps, but the idea was that if we wanted to run that particular container on a different physical machine, the entire flow would still work with this method. That was our thinking, at least, and besides... this method has worked on other environments. I may try linking them if it comes to that, but it isn't ideal for this project.

Comment: How does `/etc/resolv.conf` look like inside the container ?

Comment: ```# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: Is the hostname publicly available or is it just configured in `/etc/hosts` on the host machine ?

Comment: Did you get it work? I have similar issues.